# Reading and analyzing a UHF signal in android to judge the distance

Tags: android, radio-transmission

I am trying to build an app which is capable of analyzing a UHF signal to judge distance from my device to where the signal is transmitted from.

Comment: Are you building your own hardware? If not, what hardware are you using that has a UHF receiver with an API that your app can access?

Comment: I am building the app for android devices in general, so the app will run on the android smartphones and tablets. My goal is to transmit a UHF signal from a transmitter and receive it from my smartphone ,then analyse the signal to judge the direction and the distance it is coming from .

Comment: So you would need an UHF receiver in the device.

Comment: Well a smartphone is a UHF receiver because gsm is broadcast in the 850 and 900 bands and then 4g would go into about 1800 and 1900 as would 3g. what I  want to know is how do I build an android app to read the incoming UHF signals rather the signals in range, am I Clear ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am building the app for android devices in general

That is not possible.

> My goal is to transmit a UHF signal from a transmitter and receive it from my smartphone

That is only possible if you have a smartphone that has a [software-defined radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio) (SDR) implementation or a general-purpose UHF receiver implementation, plus associated SDKs to allow apps to work with those implementations. That is very specialized hardware.

Comment: Is there no android package , because I found a some code which is part of a project to develop an fm radio. Please take a look at this and tell me what you feel.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/FMRadio/+/master/src/com/android/fmradio/FmMainActivity.java

Comment: @Evan: "because I found a some code which is part of a project to develop an fm radio" -- that is code from a very old project that can interact with the FM receiver capability that some devices have. You cannot modify that app to somehow receive AM, or shortwave, or UHF.

Comment: If an api or a class existed to handle UHF in android my problem would be solved , I wonder which classes in android handle the internet and normal calling capabilities , because they will have to handle UHF signal because the phones receive in UHF bands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input

Comment: @Evan: "because they will have to handle UHF signal because the phones receive in UHF bands" -- no, they do not. That is handled inside of the chipsets that Qualcomm and others manufacture.

Comment: so are there no api's to communicate with the chipset ? or some way of interacting with it through software ?

Comment: @Evan: "so are there no api's to communicate with the chipset ?" -- a device manufacturer has those, and none of those will have anything to do with changing the frequency, as those are fixed by the chipset manufacturer.

Comment: You have misunderstood me slightly , I dont want to change the frequency, I want to listen for the signal and interpret messages off it and then judge the frequency to help me calculate the direction from which it originates and then on to speed in cases it is coming from a moving object.

Comment: @Evan: "I dont want to change the frequency" -- according to the question and previous comments, you do. Also, operating a UHF transmitter requires licensing, particularly if you *don't* want to change the frequency and therefore will be interfering with communications over standard bands (e.g., GSM). The only things that you have access to with respect to standard band signals are details of the cell towers, and you are not operating a cell tower (or, if you are, that requires even more licensing).